# Angular @ngrx/data custom data service how to inject another entity?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I add @ngrx/data in my application. My problem is I have to get data from other entities as well to add to the HTTP call. My code is like

```
export class ReportsModule {
    entityMetaDataMap: EntityMetadataMap = { 
        FormAData: { },
        FormBData: {},
        DataReport: {}
    }; 
    constructor(
        private entityDefinitionService: EntityDefinitionService,
        private entityDataService: EntityDataService,
        private dataReportService: DataReportService,
    ) { 
        entityDefinitionService.registerMetadataMap(this.entityMetaDataMap);
        entityDataService.registerServices({ 'DataReport': dataReportService}); 
    }
}
```

My custom data service

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportDataService extends DefaultDataService<DataReport> {
    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator,
        private formA: FormAEntityService,
        private formB: FormBEntityService
    ) { 
        super('DataReport', httpClient, httpUrlGenerator)
    } 
    
    getAll(): Observable<DataReport[]> {
        return this.formA.entities$.pipe(
            withLatestFrom(this.formB.entities$),
            switchMap(([formA, formB]) => {
                return this.dataReport.getReportSummary(
                    formA['station'],
                    // other fields from form A goes Here
                    formB['name'],
                    // other fields from form B goes here
                ).pipe(
                    map((response: DataReportResponse) => response.dataReport)
                )
            }))
        }
    }
```

How to get info from other entities in my ReportDataService? If I remove formA and formB entity service from constructor, I'm not getting any errors, otherwise, I'm getting

```
Error No Entity definition for FormAData and FormBData
```

FromA and FormB entity services are working fine in their respective components. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't used `@Injectable(providedIn: 'root')` in your entity services and that's why you need to add them in providers array in your NgModule. Moreover, make sure to import those entities before ReportDataModule.

Comment: I have directly provided the services in my module. And I tried importing before and after. But those didn't worked.